# ArrayList gives null when i set in the spinner adapter?

Tags: android, json, arraylist, model, spinner

I have two spinner.one represent country name and other one represent area name.i want to do that when i click on the country spinner and i choose the one country as example like i choose the india as per my json. then in the area spinner only area should be shown that related to that country.like example i choose india then only india area will be shown.but in my case the whole area will be shown.but i don't want it. i want to do that it shows particular area of that country.i tried to do this with model class. but when i get the country please see my onCreateOptionsMenu() method code it gives null. i don't know how can i do this?can anyone tell me ??

This is my json :-

```
 {
      "Status": 1,
      "StatusMessage": "Country and Country Area List",
      "data": [
        {
          "CountryID": "1",
          "CountryName": "India",
          "CountryArea": [
            {
              "CountryID": "1",
              "AreaID": "1",
              "AreaName": "Kuwait City(Capital)"
            },
            {
              "CountryID": "1",
              "AreaID": "2",
              "AreaName": " Hawally"
            },
           ]
        },
        {
          "CountryID": "2",
          "CountryName": "Dubai",
          "CountryArea": [
            {
              "CountryID": "2",
              "AreaID": "6",
              "AreaName": " Jeddah"
            },
            {
              "CountryID": "2",
              "AreaID": "7",
              "AreaName": " Riyadh"
            },
            ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the method where i am parsing the json :-

```
public void requestDataCountry() {


        mProgressDialog.show();
        StringRequest countrylistrequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, GlobalData.COUNTRYLISTURL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {

                            mProgressDialog.dismiss();

                            final JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response);


                            if (jObject.getString("Status").equals("1")) {

                                JSONArray jsonArray = jObject.getJSONArray("data");

                                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                    mCountryName = jsonObject.getString("CountryName");

                                    mId = jsonObject.getString("CountryID");
                                    getCountryId.add(mId);

                                    pojoCityArea.setCountryName(mCountryName);
                                    JSONArray jsonArray1 = jsonObject.getJSONArray("CountryArea");
                                    for (int j = 0; j < jsonArray1.length(); j++) {

                                        JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray1.getJSONObject(j);
                                        areaID = jsonObject1.getString("AreaID");
                                        getAreaId.add(areaID);
                                        mAreaName = jsonObject1.getString("AreaName");
                                        mAreaList.add(mAreaName);

                                    }


                                    pojoCityArea.setCountryName(mCountryName);

                                    pojoCityArea pojocityarea = new pojoCityArea();
                                    pojoCityArea.setCountryName(mCountryName )
                                    pojoCityArea.setAreaList(mAreaList);
                                    mPojoCityAreaList.add(pojoCityArea);


                                }

                                countryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            } else {

                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                        Log.e("error:", "" + volleyError.getMessage());
                        if (volleyError.getMessage() == null)
                            requestDataCountry();


                    }
                }) {


        };

        RequestQueue countryqueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());

        countryqueue.add(countrylistrequest);

    }
```

This is the onCreateOptionsMenu() method of the fragment where i setting the spinner(Country and area) :-

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);


        this.menu = menu;
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_spinner).setVisible(true);
        mCountrySpinner = (Spinner) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);


        for (PojoCityArea pojoCityArea : mPojoCityAreaList) {
            mCountryList.add(pojoCityArea.getCountryName());

        }


        countryAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, mCountryList);

        countryAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        mCountrySpinner.setAdapter(countryAdapter);


        mCountrySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                mCountrySerachId = getCountryId.get(position);
                mEditor.putString(KEY_COUNTRY_ID, mCountrySerachId);
                mEditor.commit();

                ArrayAdapter<String> areaAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, mPojoCityAreaList.get(position).getAreaList());
                areaAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1);
                mSpinnerArea.setAdapter(areaAdapter);
                mSpinnerArea.setTitle("Choose your area");



            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });


    }
```

Comment: @SripadRaj  logcat shows nothing. for (PojoCityArea pojoCityArea : mPojoCityAreaList) {
            mCountryList.add(pojoCityArea.getCountryName());

        }in this code when i print the value of mCountryList it shows empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

better you use database to resolve this problem.
First you have to insert all the country names and country ids in one table and insert all other country areas in another table along with country id, now on selection of country spinner you just pass the country id for get country areas based on that country id from database(select countryareanames from table1 where countryid='country_id';). store that into arraylist of string type and set that arraylist to spinner.